# ORACLE : group servearesults into a single column

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

i have this table

```
FLIGHT  N_flight  ORIGIN  DESTINATION
--------------------------------------------------
1111      1        LAX        MIA
1111      2        MIA        SCL 
1111      3        SCL        ARG
112       1        LAX        ATL
112       2        ATL        JFK
113       1        MIA        SEA
113       2        SEA        PHX
113       3        PHX        MSP
113       4        PHX        LIM
```

i need group by flight and in another column group all origin and destination of the flight
something like this:

```
FLIGHT  ROUTING 
--------------------------------------------------
1111     LAX - MIA - SCL - ARG
112      LAX - ATL - JFK
113      MIA - SEA - PHX - MSP - LIM
```

Comment: Looks like you need `LISTAGG`, providing your database is 11g or above.

Comment: You need to clarify your output - you have four column names in the header, but only two columns of values. In my Answer below I took a guess at what you might mean, but that's just that - a guess.

Comment: @mathguy  You're right,i edited it

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in a single aggregate query, like so:

```
with
  flights (flight, n_flight, origin, destination) as (
    select 1111, 1, 'LAX', 'MIA' from dual union all
    select 1111, 2, 'MIA', 'SCL' from dual union all 
    select 1111, 3, 'SCL', 'ARG' from dual union all
    select  112, 1, 'LAX', 'ATL' from dual union all
    select  112, 2, 'ATL', 'JFK' from dual union all
    select  113, 1, 'MIA', 'SEA' from dual union all
    select  113, 2, 'SEA', 'PHX' from dual union all
    select  113, 3, 'PHX', 'MSP' from dual union all
    select  113, 4, 'MSP', 'LIM' from dual
  )
select flight
     , min(origin)      keep (dense_rank first order by n_flight) as origin
     , min(destination) keep (dense_rank last  order by n_flight) as destination
     , listagg(origin, ' - ') within group (order by n_flight) || ' - ' ||
           min(destination) keep (dense_rank last  order by n_flight) as route
from   flights
group  by flight
;

    FLIGHT ORIGIN DESTINATION ROUTE                         
---------- ------ ----------- ------------------------------
       112 LAX    JFK         LAX - ATL - JFK               
       113 MIA    LIM         MIA - SEA - PHX - MSP - LIM   
      1111 LAX    ARG         LAX - MIA - SCL - ARG
```

Note that I changed the last row in your input data; I assume the origin should be the destination of the previous flight, you don't have two distinct segments (3 and 4) originating from the same airport.

The `WITH` clause confuses many readers. It's not part of the solution; it's there only to simulate the inputs. Remove it, and use your actual table and column names in the main query, beginning with `select flight...`